Double integral of $x^2y+y \sin(x^9)$ dxdy
I have some troubles with the following double integral (in particular the part with sinus)
$$
\iint_{D}\left[x^{2}y + y\sin\left(x^{9}\right)\right]{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\quad
\mbox{where}\quad D\ \mbox{is}\ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 2,\ y > 0
$$
I perform the following calculations where I divide the integral into two
$I_1 = \iint_D x^2y dxdy$ and $I_2 = \iint_D ysin(x^9) dxdy$ where I evaluate the first one to
$$
I_1 = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}x^2 \int_{\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2}}y dydx = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}}x^2 \bigg[\frac{y^2}{2} \bigg]_{\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2}} dx
$$
$$
= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \frac{x^4}{2} dx = \bigg[ \frac{x^5}{10} \bigg]_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{8\sqrt{2}}{10}.
$$
My troubles are with the second one
$$
I_2 = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \sin x^9 \int_{\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2}} y dydx = \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \sin x^9 \bigg[ \frac{y^2}{2} \bigg]_{\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2}} dx
$$
$$
= \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} \sin x^9 \bigg(1- \frac{2-x^2}{2} \bigg) dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} x^2 \sin x^9 dx
$$
which I cannot solve. I have tried with U-substitution obtaining the following expression $\frac{1}{2} \int_{-2}^{2} \frac{\sqrt{u} \sin u^4 \sqrt{u}}{2} du$ but this does not look very good(?). The solution should equal $\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{15}$.
Any suggestions? Thanks.
Sincerely, TS

$\int_{-\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{2}} x^2 \sin (x^9), dx=0$ because the integrand is odd.

Then I made some mistake since the first integral does not equal the solution.

next time please use \iint instead of \int\int

Indeed, your mistake in $I_1$ is in the limits for $y$. It is smaller than $\sqrt{2-x^2}$, not greater.

By symmetry, for $I_1$ you can consider $x\ge 0$:
$$I_1=2\int_0^{\sqrt 2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} x^2y\, \mathrm dy \mathrm dx=\dots$$
whereas for $I_2$, since the $\sin(x^9)$ is an odd function and $x$ assumes negative and positive values you have $I_2=0$.
